# Error en quantity cart

Tags: php

Estoy creando el updating Quantity in the cart y me arroja este error

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: qty in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\cart.php** on line **156**

aca el codigo:

```
<tr align="center">
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo $pro_id;?>"/></td>
              <td><?php echo $product_title; ?><br>
              <img src="admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $product_image;?>" width="60" height="60"/>
              </td>
              <td><input type="text" size="4" name="qty" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty'];?>"/></td>
              <?php
              if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

                  $qty = $_POST['qty'];

                   $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty'";

                   $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);

                   $_SESSION['qty']=$qty;

                   $total = $total*$qty;
              }

              ?>
              <td><?php echo "$" . $single_price; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Hola Majse_, ¿podrías aportar más datos?, como por ejemplo, el código que se supone debe crear las variables de sesión. Por otro lado, te invito a consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hola, acá esta el codigo https://pastebin.com/QvGytSD2 y gracias leere como elaborar mejores preguntas